# How to paginate through JSON object using UI bootstrap and angular Js 1 resource?

Tags: html, angularjs, json, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

**Pagination through JSON Object Using Angular Js 1 and Bootstrap UI**

May someone help me on how to paginate through json object with proper bootstrap displays and and uib-pagination paging functionality...

below is my app code

```
var app = angular
    .module("app",[
        "ngRoute",
        "ngResource",
        "ui.bootstrap"
        ])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider)
    {

        $routeProvider
        .when('/home',{
            templateUrl: 'HTML/temp/home.html',
            controller:'HomeCtrl'
        })      
        .otherwise({redirectTo:'/home'});
    }])
    .controller('HomeCtrl',['$scope','myresource','$route','$routeParams',function($scope,myresource,$route,$routeParams){
        // console logs when I click on pagination link ...
        $scope.pageChanged = function(){
            console.log("Loading Pagination ... ");
        };
        //fucntion to edit and save details 
        $scope.edit = function(myArray){

            console.log("ID : ...    !" + myArray.id);
            console.log("NUmber  ...     !" + myArray.contactdetails.number );
            //phone details fieds auto popution binding 
            $scope.phonenumber = myArray.contactdetails.number;
            $scope.email = myArray.contactdetails.email;

            //address part fieds auto popution binding
            $scope.housenumber = myArray.addressdetails.number;
            $scope.street = myArray.addressdetails.street;          
            $scope.suburb = myArray.addressdetails.suburb;
            $scope.postalcode = myArray.addressdetails.postalcode;





            $scope.data = {
                userid: myArray.id,
                number : myArray.contactdetails.number,
                email : myArray.contactdetails.email,
                streetNum : myArray.addressdetails.number,
                streetName: myArray.addressdetails.street,
                suburb: myArray.addressdetails.suburb,
                postalcode :myArray.addressdetails.postalcode
            }

            /*for(var i = 0 ; i <=  myArray.length ; i++ ){
                if($scope.editId === myArray.id){
                    $scopedata.contactdetails.number = myArray.contactdetails.number;
                    $scope.user.contactdetails.number = data[i].number;

                    console.log("phone number " + $scope.user.contactdetails.number)
                }else{

                    console.log("NOne !");
                    }
                    console.log("NOne !" + $scope.editId);
            }*/
            //

            };
        $scope.myArray=[];
        //gets data from JSON file 
        myresource.query({},function(response){         
            $scope.users  = response;   
            $scope.pagi = [];
            myArray = $scope.users;
            //object for pagination instead of premitives 
            $scope.pagi = {
                currentPage:1,
                pageSize:3,
                objlength:myArray.length            
            }   
            //console.log("Start : " + ($scope.pagi.currentPage-1) * pagi.pageSize )

            ;

        });     
    }])
    //slice and filter desired number of items 
    .filter('PagiFilter', function(){
        return function(data,start){
            return data.slice(start);   
        }
        });
        //resource factory  
    app.factory('myresource',function($resource){
            return $resource("./JSON/ScreenMockupData.json",{
            update:{method:"PUT", isArray: true}    
    })  
})
```

---

**below is html  :**

- problem 1 : pages do not link to next page
- problem 2 : bootrap buttons are not displayed.

  Search...
                      
                  
              
          
          
              
                  
                      
                          
                              UserID NumberDate of birthAgeGenderAction

  ```
                          <td>{{user.user}}</td>
                          <td>{{user.idnumber}}</td>
                          <td>{{user.dob}}</td>
                          <td>{{user.age}}</td>
                          <td>{{user.gender}}</td>                            
                          <td><form method="post" ><button type="submit" id = "{{user.id}}" ng-model="editId" value="{{user.id}}" ng-value="{{user.id}}" ng-click = "edit(user)">Edit user{{user.id}}</button></td>
                          </form></td>    
                          </tr>

                          </a>
                      </table>
              </div>              

          </div>
          <div  class='btn btn-default'>

              <ul uib-pagination total-items="users.length" items-per-page = "pagi.pageSize" ng-model="pagi.currentPage" data-ng-show="users.length" ng-change  = "pageChanged()"> </ul>
          </div>
  ```

******************Index.html**************************************

---

```
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>User Management System</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">                
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "container">   
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>      
        <script src="./JS/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>        
        <script src="./js/node_modules/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./JS/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">   

        <script src="./js/node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap.js" ></script>
        <script src="./js/node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js" ></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/styles.css">
        <script src="./JS/application.js"></script>
    </body>     
</html>
```

Comment: NB : REFERENCE TO NG-REPEAT . My ng-repeat is not properly formATED FOR sTACK :<tr ng-repeat = 'user in users | filter:(pagi.currentPage-1) * pagi.pageSize | limitTo: pagi.pageSize | filter: searchTerm:strict'>